# Ubuntu 20.04 dotnet tool is not available after dotnet reinstall

Tags: 20.04, dotnet

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. After some recent update of Ubuntu - my dotnet cli went crazy and stopped working.
After that I have completely removed it from my PC
Then tried to reinstall it back with:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

But `dotnet`
Command still gives:

```
Command 'dotnet' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install dotnet-sdk
```

I have tried to install dotnet with recommended by Microsoft `dotnet-install.sh`, but result is the same.
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You can see which files are in the package with `dpkg -L dotnet-sdk`. You can ask which package provides `dotnet` with `dpkg -S dotnet`, or see all packages with "dotnet" in their names with `apt-cache search dotnet`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the variables to your environment, check it here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#set-environment-variables-system-wide

In my case, the installation script didn't do that (it should but no).